# Cannot execute a python program which is handling a local file using PHP

Tags: php, python, html, raspberry-pi

I have a webpage that will dynamically send a random password to my email account. I am using python's smtplib for it. The stand alone program is working pretty well. And it is also writing it to a file. Here's the password generator python code.

```
import random
import smtplib

s=""
l = random.randint(10,14)

while len(s)<l:
    i=random.randint(48,122)
    if(i!=58 and i!=59 and i!=94 and i!=96):
        s=s+chr(i)    



file = open("pwd.txt","w")
file.write(s)
file.close()

svr = smtplib.SMTP("smtp.gmail.com:587")
svr.starttls()
svr.login("*****","******")

svr.sendmail("****","****","Password is "+str(s))
svr.quit()
```

I have also written a python code to verify the password. It'll read from pwd.txt file and verify it. These are working fine.

But the problem is I have a made a HTML page with PHP and whenever I load the page it should create a file and send an email right? That isn't happening. Here is the HTML code for the page I made.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>  
<body>
<b>Enter password</b>
<form action="GET.php" method="post">

<input type="text" name="pwd"><br>

<input type="submit">
</form>

</body>
<?php
exec("sudo python /home/pi/Desktop/PWD/pwdgenerator.py");
?>
</html>
```

I am using Apache as well but I don't think the problem is there.

Comment: What happens when you execute `sudo python /home/pi/Desktop/PWD/pwdgenerator.py` in your Linux shell? Also do you have PHP's `exec` function enabled?

Comment: Works perfectly fine. The file is created which holds the value of the password as well.

Comment: What about PHP's `exec`? Is it in the `disable_functions`block of your php.ini? http://us2.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.disable-functions

Comment: If I put a echo and get the output on webpage. The current password is shown. But the file is not generated.

Comment: Yes, but does PHP have permission to use `exec`? Usually system administrators disable it. That's why I'm asking.

Comment: Yes it has. I have done work with exec() many times around.

Comment: You realize that `sudo` requires you to enter a password which in this case you don't provide. You should better fix the permissions on the Python script using `chown` to allow your webserver and/or php to execute it.

Comment: In my case the sudo doesn't require a password. I have run the program from the terminal without providing a password at all.

Comment: And it is able to execute the script as I can see the output on the webpage but the only problem is the file is not created.

Comment: This might be the case for the terminal user (e.g. root), but try and log in to the shell as `www-data` or `apache` and see if it does require a password or not. Looks to me like you got yourself a permission lock-out.

Comment: Well, ok, how about you specify an absolute path to the file and not just a relative?

Comment: Can you guide me how to give file handling privileges to PHP?

Comment: Well, first of all please open and write to your file in python in a `try` ... `except` block and preferably use it in a `with` statement. Use the examples listed here https://docs.python.org/3.6/tutorial/errors.html. Then check which user is actually running your PHP script when you invoke it via your webserver. Usually it's `www-data` or `apache`, but I can't say for sure. Then when you have that user, `chown` the directory inside which Python makes this `pwd.txt` file so that the webserver user can write to it. Probably something like `chown www-data:www-data /home/pi/Desktop/PWD/`.